# Android Pin Code Activity

Tags: java, android

I want to make an ATM app for our school project. But i can't do this

For example. I launched the app and it showed the splash screen. After that, it would launch the Pin Code activity then if its correct, it would go directly to the main menu

Now in this i have Withdraw and Profile
If i click either of this. It would launch the either Withdraw Activity or Profile Activity. Now i want these two to get block by the same Pin Code activity again BUT the after the pin got entered correctly it would go to the withdraw or profile activity. Not back to the main menu

I really tried my best to explain what i wanted. I don't know what is it called, nor how to do it. But that is what i need right now.

Comment: `startActivityForResult` is basically what you need... Read the official documentation, come back when you have a clear question / implemented code

Comment: This is an opportunity to learn about making activities reusable.  As @cricket_007 suggests, design it to be started for result and return either the PIN itself or a pass/fail value back to the calling activity.

Comment: I have found a solution, But thanks for that startActivityForResult. Another piece that i learned and used.